# Importing OpenCV in IntelliJ Does Not Resolve

Tags: opencv, intellij-idea

I have a Python project where I'm using OpenCV as one of the libraries. When I imported the project in IntelliJ, it would show highlight on all the places where I use OpenCV. It would also not show IntelliSense suggestions on the available methods in OpenCV.

```
Cannot find reference 'imshow' in '__init__.py | cv2'
```

I'm using it as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Any ideas on how to get this solved? I'm on IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please feel free to vote/comment for this issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24535/opencv-contrib-python-analysis-doesnt-work-properly-Cannot-find-reference- in order to increase its priority and be notified about any updates.

I apologize for the inconvenience.